# Qt Widget with Transparent Background

Tags: python, qt, transparency, pyside

(I'm using PySide, but I think the answer would be the same/similar for any language bindings).

I'm trying to take the shaped clock example, located [here](https://github.com/pyside/Examples/blob/master/examples/widgets/shapedclock.py), and cause the face of the clock (circle) to be transparent so that all I see are the clock hands and minute ticks.  As is, when the example runs, it looks like [this](https://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qt-widgets-shapedclock-example.html).  I'm using Windows 7.

So far, I've tried the following (in the constructor):

- `self.setAttribute(QtCore.Qt.WA_TranslucentBackground)`

  - Clock appears (has presence in task bar), but I can't see it anywhere
- `self.setAttribute(QtCore.Qt.WA_NoSystemBackground)`

  - Clock appears, but has solid black background.
- `self.setWindowOpacity(0.5)`

  - Clock appears, but entire clock is transparent.  I want the background (face) to be transparent, but I want the clock hands to be visible.

Comment: For the record, I think the widget does have a transparent background, but it's obviously sitting on something else that doesn't.  Is that a correct statement?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Got it!

This is from the original example code (constructor):

```
    ...
    self.setWindowFlags(self.windowFlags() | QtCore.Qt.FramelessWindowHint)
    ...
```

Here is the modified (and working per my question) version:

```
    ...
    self.setWindowFlags(QtCore.Qt.FramelessWindowHint)
    self.setAttribute(QtCore.Qt.WA_TranslucentBackground)
    ...
```

Removing the `self.windowFlags()` was the part I was missing.  (I'm not exactly sure why I needed to remove this or why it was there to begin with... still much to learn).

Comment: Hm.  I hadn't heard of WA_TranslucentBackground before.  I tried adding it to the clock sample and ran it under KDE, and all I got was a solid black background to the widget.  What else did you change in the code and what result did you get?

Comment: Did you notice the change above in the `self.setWindowFlags` line?

Comment: So one should find out which flags are set by default by `self.windowFlags()`.

Answer (score 7):

If I remember correctly, you should have set its stylesheet also:

```
self.setWindowFlags(QtCore.Qt.FramelessWindowHint)
self.setAttribute(QtCore.Qt.WA_TranslucentBackground)
self.setStyleSheet("background:transparent;")
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: It depends. The widget itself has a transparent background because of the attribute `QtCore.Qt.WA_TranslucentBackground` and doesn't need the style sheet itself but child widgets contained in the widget however that have `autoFillBackground()==True` by default should have it unset or should have set `QtCore.Qt.WA_TranslucentBackground` or indeed like you say should have a transparent background color set by a style sheet which is then inherited.

Comment: Ya, in my case I need the 3rd line to set the stylesheet too. Since, I am using kvantum and the style of active theme seemingly overrides any non-transparent background. But again this is my assumption.

Answer (score 1):

in the clock example ther is :

```
void ShapedClock::resizeEvent(QResizeEvent * /* event */)
 {
     int side = qMin(width(), height());
     QRegion maskedRegion(width() / 2 - side / 2, height() / 2 - side / 2, side,
                          side, QRegion::Ellipse);
     setMask(maskedRegion);
 }
```

the "setMask" do the round shape
but there's the same in PySide :

```
def resizeEvent(self, event):
        side = min(self.width(), self.height())
        maskedRegion = QtGui.QRegion(self.width()/2 - side/2, self.height()/2 - side/2, side, side, QtGui.QRegion.Ellipse)
        self.setMask(maskedRegion)
```

so it should work too ?

Comment: I clarified my question a little bit.  The code you site above does cause everything outside of the face of the clock to be transparent, but I'm trying to make the clock face itself transparent (everything but the clock hands and minute tick marks).