# pyqt : transparent background QGLWidget

Tags: pyqt, transparent, qglwidget

[image]

I hope to make a QGLWidget that has a transparent background, like a figure above.
It's a cpp code and I don't understand the some parts of it. As far as I know, it uses window handle, drawing context, and so on. But I'm poor at C and C++. I've used Python and PyQt, so it seems like a Atlantis for me. Is there any idea for QGLWidget that has a transparent background?

## ADD

```py
from PyQt4.QtCore import Qt
from PyQt4.QtGui import QApplication, QColor
from PyQt4.QtOpenGL import QGLWidget

from OpenGL import GL
import sys

class TransGLWidget(QGLWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QGLWidget.__init__(self, parent)
        self.setWindowFlags(Qt.FramelessWindowHint)
        self.setAttribute(Qt.WA_TranslucentBackground, True)
        self.setGeometry(200, 100, 640, 480)

    def initializeGL(self):
        self.qglClearColor(QColor(0, 0, 0, 0))

    def resizeGL(self, w, h):
        GL.glViewport(0, 0, w, h)
        GL.glMatrixMode(GL.GL_PROJECTION)
        GL.glLoadIdentity()
        x = float(w) / h
        GL.glFrustum(-x, x, -1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 10.0)
        GL.glMatrixMode(GL.GL_MODELVIEW)
        GL.glLoadIdentity()

    def paintGL(self):
        GL.glClear(GL.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT)   

        GL.glBegin(GL.GL_TRIANGLES)
        GL.glColor3f(1.0, 0.0, 0.0)
        GL.glVertex3f(-1.0, 1.0, -3.0)
        GL.glColor3f(0.0, 1.0, 0.0)
        GL.glVertex3f(1.0, 1.0, -3.0)
        GL.glColor3f(0.0, 0.0, 1.0)
        GL.glVertex3f(0.0, -1.0, -3.0)
        GL.glEnd()

app = QApplication(sys.argv)
widget = TransGLWidget()    
widget.show()
app.exec_()
```

I try with above code, but it shows me nothing. (It seems a whole transparent widget.) If I get rid of "setAttribute", "setWindowFlags", is shows up a triangle. Is there any miss at the code?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Qt Widget with Transparent Background](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7667552/qt-widget-with-transparent-background)

Answer (score 1):

Translated into Python from [this C++ solution](http://qt-project.org/forums/viewthread/23388/#113123). The semicolon at the end has been removed, `::` has been replaced with `.`, and `True` has been capitalized. The main source of difficulty is that `setAttribute` and `setWindowFlags` are actually methods of the `QGLWidget`, so `self.` has been added. Just add this in the `__init__()` constructor of your QGLWidget`.

```
self.setAttribute(Qt.WA_TranslucentBackground, True)
```

You can add
    self.setWindowFlags(Qt.FramelessWindowHint | Qt.WindowStaysOnTopHint)

if you want the window to be on top of others and have no frame.

Comment: I tried as you suggested, but I failed. I wrote my code, so can you check my fault?

Comment: @Hyun-geunKim It's working for me; which OS are you using? I think it won't work on Windows XP because it doesn't use a compositing window manager.

Comment: I'm using Windows 7. It means that in my system transparency is impossible?

Comment: @Hyun-geunKim. It might be possible. See this [Windows Seven Forum thread](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/283-transparency-enable-disable.html) for details.

Comment: Hi, @Hyun-geun Kim Did you ever solved this transprency issue on a gL widget ?