# PyQt5 Transparent Window Bug?

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, windows-10, pyqt5

I've been working on a screenshot application written in Python (v. 3.5) using PyQt5 (v 5.7), but I've been developing it on MacOs. The app works *as intended* on Mac, but when I pulled the repo onto my Windows 10 machine I can't get the app to render properly.

Basically I want a fullscreen transparent window, here's the code I am using. As it is, nothing renders at all. (`Qt` is imported from `QtCore`)

```
    self.setWindowFlags(self.windowFlags() | Qt.FramelessWindowHint)
    self.setAttribute(Qt.WA_TranslucentBackground)
#Maximize the window
    self.showFullScreen()
#Render the window
    self.activateWindow()
    self.setFocus()
    self.show()
```

When I comment out `self.setAttribute(Qt.WA_TranslucentBackground)` it will actually render (but with the gray-ish background).

I've tried removing `self.windowFlags()` from `setWindowFlags()` to no avail (as seen in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7667552/qt-widget-with-transparent-background) answer).

Also tried it without `self.setFocus()` and `self.activateWindow()`

Is this a bug? or am I doing something wrong here.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Try using `self.setWindowOpacity(0.5)` instead of `self.setAttribute(Qt.WA_TranslucentBackground)` and adjust your opacity wanted.
You can look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37530276/transparent-widgets-inside-transparent-frame-pyqt5) for more details. From what I understand you want full background transparent and visible widgets ?

Answer (score 0):

Try using the `windowOpacity` prop or method `setWindowOpacity(double)`

http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#windowOpacity-prop